# How do I assign values to variables and then display it in the view with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm new to Laravel, I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial

> https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data

I want to assign a value to a variable and then display it in the view but I don't know where I should do it. I tried to add this snippet

```
Route::get('greeting', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['name' => 'Samantha']);
});
```

to the `web.php` file and then display it in the view like this `hello, {{name}}` but I either get an error or just a plain text:

> hello, {{name}}

I'm reading the documentation but I can't figure out where or how to assign values to variables and then display it.

My view named `welcome.blade.php` has this:

```
<h1>Example</h1>

Hello, {$name}
```

In my `web.php` file I have this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;



Route::get('greeting', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['name' => 'Samantha']);
});
```

It doesn't give me any error. Just shows `Hello {$name}` instead of `Samantha`

Comment: did you name your view correctly?  `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` ?

Comment: Yes. I did but let me check again. Yes I did. I don't think the problem is displaying the data but assign values. Am I doing it right? I have tried `@{{$name}}` `{{$name}}` `@{{name}}`

Comment: Which the error message you got?

Comment: Actually I got that error because I tried to display `{{name}}` instead of `@{{name}}` . The error: `Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'` . I don't know what I'm doing wrong, Where am I supposed to assign values to variables? In the `web.php` file? Now it just shows `Hello {{name}}`, no errors.

Comment: its PHP ... variables start with a `$` ... the way you are passing the data to the view is **correct**

Comment: Thank you but I thought I didn't need that since I'm using blade template ( I don't know how it works yet) but anyway, I tried and I got this: `Undefined variable: name` I tried `hello, {{$name}}` and also `hello, @{{$name}}`  the latter didn't give me any result just a plain text.

Comment: paste up the full content of this view file ... and stop using `@{{ }}`, that is so you can have the literal `{{ ... }}` in the output

Comment: OK Thank you. I will update my question.

Comment: my guess would be that you are not hitting this `greeting` route and you are hitting a different route that just happens to also be returning this view, but not passing it the needed data ... if i had to guess

Comment: I was thiking that too because I added the .html extension But I also tried without .html extension and same problem.

Comment: its `{{ ... }}` not `{ ... }` ... you have to follow the documentation ... and the files must have the extension `.blade.php` to be a Blade template

Comment: Thank you all. I figured it out. I had a duplicated Route for the same `welcome` view I thought I had deleted. Thank you and I'm sorry.

Comment: @NewUser2 glad you figured it out ... good luck with Laravel and have fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the `$` sign in your blade.

```
hello, {{ $name }}
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the same result. I think the variable hasn't been assigned. I'm not sure where I should do it.

Comment: Thank you.It worked now. I had a duplicated `route`.